# does the src field in an ip route entry have any effect on forwarding traffic?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iproute2

1. does the `src` field in `ip route` have any affect on forwarding traffic? or is it only significant for output traffic?
2. what is the significance of an `ip route` entry that specifies both `dev` and `src`, where `src` does not belong to `dev` (but rather to a different device in the system)?

Answer (score 1):

When adding a route to a multihomed host, you might want to have control over the source IP address your host is sending from when starting communications using this route. This is what `src` is for.

Therefore to answer your question by point :

1. No, it has no effect on forwarding traffic, it is only for local generated traffic.
2. You can use bot dev and src to double-check if the `src` IP entered corresponds to the correct `dev` interfaces. If the source IP mentioned is not on the device specified you will get an error.

Comment: actually when the `src` is *not* an address of `dev`, there is no error.

moreover, i found a comment in `understanding linux network internals` that briefly addresses this (`35.7.2. Preferred Source Address Selection`) but it doesn't go into detail about when/how to make use of this.

i encountered such a configuration in a legacy system i'm working on, and was wondering about the reason for it.

Comment: [root@localhost ~]# ip r add 1.1.1.1 via 10.0.2.1 dev enp0s3 src 2.2.2.2
RTNETLINK answers: Invalid argument
[root@localhost ~]# ip r add 1.1.1.1 via 10.0.2.1 dev enp0s3
[root@localhost ~]# ip r
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3  proto static  metric 100
1.1.1.1 via 10.0.2.1 dev enp0s3
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15  metric 100
[root@localhost ~]# ip r add 1.1.1.1 via 10.0.2.1 dev enp0s3 src 10.0.2.15
[root@localhost ~]# ip r


Centos7/rhel7 detects it as an error .

Comment: You can force a foreign src address by tuning the kernel a bit to allow bindings on non local IP's . How ever this is used on special situation like VRRP, LVS, etc ... or when you just need to generate traffic with a specific IP for audits and tests(but expect no return traffic!)